# When i am updating wordpress , this error is shown

Tags: wordpress

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; PclZip has a deprecated constructor in /wp-admin/includes/class-pclzip.php on line 190

Comment: Share your current version and new version?

Comment: current version is WordPress 4.0.3 and new version is 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manually download wp and upload wp-admin & wp-includes & wp-content files to your wp installed path using ftp.